# SQL Server - What's in that log backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, audit, transaction-log

So I noticed that one of my log backups is about 1000x larger than normal.  I'd like to see what is in there.  Is there something I can use to read it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party tools

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm (Free but SQL2000 only - You don't state a version)

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp (Quite pricy though it seems to have a trial version. I'm not sure what limitations this might have.)

I guess if you're that curious and haven't got a spare $999 you could use the backups to restore the relevant 2 copies of the database then do a data compare between the 2 versions.

Comment: Well, it's SQL 2k, so I'm in luck.  The data compare option sounds interesting.  Any tool recommendations for this?

Thanks!